# Add checkbox and input to onepage checkout, and store to database

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I need to add a custom checkbox and under the checkbox a textarea to onepage checkout page, to a page where you select your payment method and review delivery address.

This data then needs to be stored to DB, preferably with the order itself.

Is this possible to make by myself? I've found the extensions, but I don't wanna shell out that kind of money.

any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

use this free extension , this may help

https://marketplace.magento.com/infobeans-magento2-oscomments.html